# Git hook fails ONLY on commit

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit

## Executive summary

I have a project with a custom pre-commit hook, with a tree that looks something like this:

```
parent
|
- .git - hooks - pre-commit
|
- smoketests - argument_tests.sh
|
- bitshuffle.py
```

When I run .git/hooks/pre-commit, it runs perfectly, and every test passes. However, when I run `git commit`, some tests fail. My index is exactly the same as my working tree. I have no idea what's going wrong.

Thanks for your help.

## Details

### Status

```
$ git status
On branch staging
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/staging'.
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   smoketest/argument_tests.sh
        renamed:    smoketest/do_test.sh -> smoketest/library_tests.sh
```

### Traceback

```
$ git commit
Running tests...

When run with no args, prints help... PASSED
When run with '-h', prints help... PASSED
When given bad compresstype, prints help... PASSED
When given bad editor, prints editor not found... FAILED

'Editor /nonexistent not found' does not match logfile

        Nothing to decode or nothing matched spec. Aborting.


When given bad input, prints file not found... PASSED

1 tests failed.
```

### Runnning pre-commit on its own

```
$ .git/hooks/pre-commit
Running tests...

When run with no args, prints help... PASSED
When run with '-h', prints help... PASSED
When given bad compresstype, prints help... PASSED
When given bad editor, prints editor not found... PASSED
When given bad input, prints file not found... PASSED

0 tests failed.
```

### Contents of pre-commit

```
#!/bin/sh

## custom
# smoketesting
if ! smoketest/library_tests.sh; then exit 1; fi;
# arguments
if ! smoketest/argument_tests.sh; then exit 1; fi;
# codestyle 
if ! pycodestyle *.py; then exit 1; fi;
```

### Diff

```
$ git diff --cached
diff --git smoketest/argument_tests.sh smoketest/argument_tests.sh
new file mode 100755
index 0000000..0133819
--- /dev/null
+++ smoketest/argument_tests.sh
@@ -0,0 +1,90 @@
+#!/bin/bash
+
+# .SHELLDOC
+
+# Smoketests for argument handling. Exit code is # of failed tests.
+# Heavily influenced by existing smoketests.
+
+# .ENDOC
+
+TEST_DIR="`readlink -e $(dirname "$0")`"
+BITSHUFFLE="$TEST_DIR/../bitshuffle.py"
+TESTS_FAILED=0
+
+if [ ! -x "$BITSHUFFLE" ] ; then
+        echo "FATAL: '$BITSHUFFLE' does not exist"
+        exit 9999
+fi
+
+# Note: of necessity, the following can only test non-interactive
+# situations. Interactive tests are not a priority at the current moment.
+
+print_log_file() {
+# takes 1 parameter, a text file
+        while read -r line; do
+                printf "\t$line\n"
+        done < $1
+        printf "\n\n"
+}
+
+
+expect_usage_error () {
+        LOG_FILE="/tmp/`uuidgen`"
+        $BITSHUFFLE $@ > "$LOG_FILE" 2>&1
+        if grep -q "usage: .*" $LOG_FILE; then
+                echo "PASSED"
+        else
+                printf "FAILED\n\n"
+
+                printf "\t'usage: .*' does not match logfile\n\n" 
+                print_log_file $LOG_FILE
+                TESTS_FAILED=`echo "$TESTS_FAILED + 1" | bc`
+                rm -f $LOG_FILE
+        fi
+}
+
+printf "Running tests...\n\n"
+
+printf "When run with no args, prints help... "
+expect_usage_error
+
+printf "When run with '-h', prints help... "
+expect_usage_error -h
+
+printf "When given bad compresstype, prints help... "
+expect_usage_error -t gmander
+
+printf "When given bad editor, prints editor not found... "
+LOG_FILE="/tmp/`uuidgen`"
+$BITSHUFFLE --editor /nonexistent > "$LOG_FILE" 2>&1
+if [ "`cat $LOG_FILE`" = "Editor /nonexistent not found" ]; then
+        echo "PASSED"
+else
+        printf "FAILED\n\n"
+
+        printf "'Editor /nonexistent not found' does not match logfile\n\n"
+
+        print_log_file $LOG_FILE
+        TESTS_FAILED="`echo $TESTS_FAILED + 1 | bc`"
+        rm -f $LOG_FILE
+fi
+
+LOG_FILE="/tmp/`uuidgen`"
+printf "When given bad input, prints file not found... "
+$BITSHUFFLE --input /nonexistent/nope > "$LOG_FILE" 2>&1
+if [ "`cat $LOG_FILE`" = "Error: Input file not found" ]; then
+    echo "PASSED"
+else
+    printf "FAILED\n\n"
+
+    printf "\t'Error: Input file not found' \
+             does not match logfile\n\n"
+
+    print_log_file $LOG_FILE
+    TESTS_FAILED=`echo $TESTS_FAILED + 1 | bc`
+    rm -f $LOG_FILE
+fi
+
+printf "\n$TESTS_FAILED tests failed.\n"
+exit $TESTS_FAILED
+
diff --git smoketest/do_test.sh smoketest/library_tests.sh
similarity index 100%
rename from smoketest/do_test.sh
rename to smoketest/library_tests.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Program responded differently if terminal was interactive vs. non-interactive. Running tests from a script made terminal non-interactive.

The culprit:

```
        if stdin.isatty() and args.input == '/dev/stdin':
        # ask the user to paste the packets into $VISUAL
            is_tmp = True
            if not args.editor:
                args.editor = find_editor()

            if not check_for_file(args.editor):
                print("Editor %s not found" % args.editor)
                sys.exit(4)
```

If `stdin.isatty()` returned false, this bit would never run.